# Update dropdown option value and script onchange rather than onclick

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am simply trying to do away with the 'Result' button in the following script. I am happy for the first dropdown options to be selected on page load, and the script to already have run based on this output:

```js
var dd1 = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var dd2 = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
var res = document.getElementById("result");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function getSpecificText(v1, v2) {
    var con = v1.toString() + v2.toString();
    var res = "";
    switch (con) {
      case "500012":
        res = text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        500024 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        500036 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        500048 ":
                res = "
        text4 ";
                break;
            case "
        500060 ":
                res = "
        text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        1000012 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        1000024 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        1000036 ":
                res = "
        text4 ";
                break;
            case "
        1000048 ":
                res = "
        text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        1000060 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        1500012 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        1500024 ":
                res = "
        text4 ";
                break;
            case "
        1500036 ":
                res = "
        text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        1500048 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        1500060 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        2000012 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        2000024 ":
                res = "
        text4 ";
                break;
            case "
        2000036 ":
                res = "
        text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        2000048 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        2000060 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        2500012 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            case "
        2500024 ":
                res = "
        text4 ";
                break;
            case "
        2500036 ":
                res = "
        text1 ";
                break;
            case "
        2500048 ":
                res = "
        text2 ";
                break;
            case "
        2500060 ":
                res = "
        text3 ";
                break;
            // ...
        }
        return res
    }
    
    function getSelected() {
        var v1 = dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].value;
        var v2 = dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].value;
        output.innerHTML = getSpecificText(v1, v2);
    }
    
    res.addEventListener("
        click ", getSelected);
```

```html
<p>
  Value:
  <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="15000">15000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="25000">25000</option>
  </select>
  Months:
  <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
  </select>
  Months
  <button id="result">Result</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to use the `onchange` event on the drop down list elements. Something like this:

```
dd1.addEventListener("change", getSelected);
dd2.addEventListener("change", getSelected);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dnj0rmab/)

If you want to show the output when the page is first loaded just call the `getSelected` function directly in your javascript:

```
getSelected();
```

As this function relies on DOM elements, you will need to ensure they are loaded. This can be done either by putting the script tag at the end of the document, or by using a `window.onload` event, like so:

```
window.onload = function(){
    getSelected();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that however, and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I posted example, it does work. Check your console for error, if you are using that exact script then you have lots of error with your strings not being closed properly (due to newlines) in the switch, that might just be how you formatted the question though

Comment: Ah yes sorry it does work. Would you know how to get it to show a result when it loads also?

Comment: yeah just call the `getSelected();` function outside of an event, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dnj0rmab/1/)